# LookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to send odom message: [The code is](http://pastebin.com/AhFWug7i), but it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 237, in run
    self.last_update_ros_time = rospy.Time.now()   
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/rostime.py", line 155, in now
    return get_rostime()   
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/rostime.py", line 209, in get_rostime
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?")
ROSInitException: time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?

[INFO] [WallTime: 1436785911.264067]
Starting odom node Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/robotics/Documents/ros/src/navigation_car/odom_sender.py", line 49, in <module>
    trans,rot = tf_listener.lookupTransform(odom_frame, base_frame, current_time )
tf.LookupException: "odom" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

Tf-tree is normal, tf-echo odom base_link works properly

**Edit 0:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/robotics/Documents/ros/src/navigation_car/odom_sender.py",
> line 51, in 
> trans,rot = tf_listener.lookupTransform(odom_frame,
> base_frame, rospy.Time()  )
> tf.LookupException: "odom" passed to
> lookupTransform argument target_frame
> does not exist.

**Edit 1:**
new error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/robotics/Documents/ros/src/navigation_car/odom_sender.py",
> line 66, in 
> odom_pub.publish(odom)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py",
> line 843, in publish
> self.impl.publish(data)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py",
> line 1027, in publish
> serialize_message(b, self.seq, message)   File
> "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py",
> line 152, in serialize_message
> msg.serialize(b)   File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nav_msgs/msg/_Odometry.py",
> line 167, in serialize
> buff.write(_struct_7d.pack(_x.pose.pose.position.x,
> _x.pose.pose.position.y, _x.pose.pose.position.z, _x.pose.pose.orientation.x, _x.pose.pose.orientation.y, _x.pose.pose.orientation.z, _x.pose.pose.orientation.w)) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no
> attribute 'x'

**Edit 2:**
All is well) This is [code](http://pastebin.com/JsUF0kEY)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213577/lookuptransform-argument-target_frame-does-not-exist/) by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-13**:
please be more specific. This is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, there are two errors.

the one with `init_node()` is coming from your tf_listener() being a global variable.
Put this one after the `init_node()` call, then it shoudl work.

I'm not sure about the other one. Does this still occur after having the tf_listener setup correctly?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on 2015-07-13**:
i corrected the [code](http://pastebin.com/sEpv3VNS). Now it give on error (see edit).